# If $f$ is integrable and $E_\alpha=\{x\mid |f(x)|>\alpha\}$ for $\alpha\geq 0$, show that $\int|f(x)|dx=\int_0^\infty m(E_\alpha)d\alpha$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f$ an integrable function and $E_\alpha=\{x\mid |f(x)|>\alpha\}$ for $\alpha\geq 0$. Show that $$\int |f(x)|dx=\int_0^\infty  m(E_\alpha)d\alpha.$$

**In the case where $f$ is simple :**

Let $f=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j1_{F_j}$ where $F_j$ are disjoins and $0=a_0<a_1<a_2<...<a_n<a_{n+1}=\infty $. If $a_k\leq \alpha<a_{k+1}$, then $E_\alpha=F_{k+1}\cup ...\cup F_n$. Then,

$$\int_0^\infty  m(E_\alpha)d\alpha\underset{(*)}{=} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(a_{k+1}-a_k)\sum_{j=k+1}^n m(F_j)=...$$
I don't understand the equality $(*)$, where does it comes from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write:

$$\int_0^{\infty}m(E_{\alpha})\,d\alpha=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{a_k}^{a_{k+1}}m(E_{\alpha})\,d\alpha$$

and use the form of $E_{\alpha}$ on each interval. (Note that $f\leq a_n$ so $E_{\alpha}=\emptyset$ for $\alpha\geq a_n$).